# Is it possible to create a neural network, which behaves like $f(x) = x$?

Tags: neural-networks

Let's assume $x \in R, 0<x<1$

The neural network has one input and one output, and contains one or more hidden layer.

is it possible to create a network, where if the input is x, then the output is also x?

$f(x) \approx x$

---

**Edit**

The sigmoid function is: $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

Comment: Do you mean creating it in such a way that this happens by definition, or just can a NN be trained to replicate its input if it has some specified structure.

Comment: I'm curious if it is possible to create it by definition. If it can be created, then it can be trained too.

Comment: If $x \in K$ where $K$ is compact then sure, provided that activation function is any non-stupid choice. This is because neural networks are universal approximators - they can replicate any continuous function on a compact set to any desired degree of accuracy. If $x \in \mathbb R$ then it will depend on the activation function - if the activation function is bounded, and you want $f(x) \approx x$ to hold for all $x$, then you are screwed. But for a suitable unbounded activation function (e.g., the identity function, or maybe even ReLUs) it is trivial.

Comment: The sigmoid function is: $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

Comment: @guy, why not work that up into an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some conditions we might need. For example, we need to know

- Are there any conditions on the activation function $\sigma(x)$? It seems like you have in mind $\sigma(x) = (1 + e^{-x})^{-1}$, but the activation function you are using is not explicitly stated.
- Are there any conditions on the space $R$ where the $x$'s live? In your question you set $0 < x < 1$.

If we assume that (1) $R$ is (contained in) a compact set and (2) $\sigma(x)$ is non-constant, continuous, and bounded on $R$ then it follows that there exists a neural network with activation function $\sigma(x)$ which approximates *any* continuous function $f(x)$ on $R$. So, in particular, we can approximate the function $f(x) = x$. This is the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

If we assume that $R = (-\infty, \infty)$ then we need $\sigma(x)$ to be unbounded. To see why, note that if $|\sigma(x)| \le K$ and $f(x)$ is a neural network, then $f(x)$ is also bounded. If $f(x)$ is bounded then it cannot approximate the function $x \mapsto x$ for $x > \sup_x |f(x)|$. So, we need $\sigma(x)$ to be unbounded to have any shot. There are a few activation functions which are unbounded; for example $\sigma(x) = \max\{0, x\}$ gives us $x = \sigma(x) - \sigma(-x)$. And $\sigma(x) = x$ also works.

Another interesting possibility, which might be used in practice, is $\sigma(x) = \log(1 + e^x)$ for which $\sigma(x) \approx x$ for large $\max\{0, x\}$. So you could get $\sigma(x) \approx x$ for large $x$ by looking at $\log(1 + e^{x}) - \log(1 + e^{-x})$. The problem would be making the approximation work simultaneously for large and small $x$ using only these units, which may not be possible.